# exibição de conteúdo de arquivo txt em php

Tags: php, html5, visual-studio-code, txt

Olá, estou tentando ler um arquivo txt criado com dados inseridos pelos usuários de um site (nome, email, empresa e telefone) e quero exibir as informações dentro do arquivo txt utilizando php.

Meu código até o momento está assim:

```
<? 
                    $arquivo = fopen('Log_Cadastro_de_ident.txt', 'r');

                    $dados = array();

                    while(!feof($arquivo)){

                        $dados[] = explode('*', $arquivo);
                        
                                          };

                    //fechamento do arquivo
                    fclose($arquivo); 
                ?>
                <div class="card-consultar-chamado">
                   <p class="identif"> <?= $dados[0] ?> </p>
                   <p class="identif_1"> <?= $dados[1] ?> </p>
                   <p class="identif_1"> <?= $dados[2] ?> </p>
                   <p class="identif_1"> <?= $dados[3] ?> </p>
                </div>
```

O problema é que quando executo o código ele me passa as seguintes informações na tela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Está faltando o "fgets" para pegar o conteudo da linha, tenta assim:

```
<?php

$dados = array();

$arquivo = fopen('Log_Cadastro_de_ident.txt', 'r');
while (!feof($arquivo)) {
   $line = fgets($file_handle);
   $dados[] = explode('*', $line );
}
fclose($file_handle);
```

Obs: Se você mandar o arquivo de texto, fica mais facil de propor uma solução

Comment: Deu certo cara, muito obrigado!! Próxima vez anexo o arquivo de texto